# Metpy Precipitable Water Given Arguments with Incorrect Units

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, metpy

I am trying to do a simple calculation using Metpy's precipitable water function. The code below matches their example:

```
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
    from metpy.units import units
    import numpy as np

    pressure = np.array([1000, 500]) * units.hPa
    dewpoint = np.array([11.5, -25]) * units.degC
    pw = precipitable_water(pressure, dewpoint)

    print(pw)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\pwscript2.py", line 7, in <module> mpcalc.precipitable_water(dew, pressure)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py", line 1329, in wrapper result = func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metpy\units.py", line 319, in wrapper _check_units_inner_helper(func, sig, defaults, dims, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metpy\units.py", line 306, in _check_units_inner_helper raise ValueError(msg)
    ValueError: This function changed in 1.0--double check that the function is being called properly.
    `precipitable_water` given arguments with incorrect units: `pressure` requires " 
    [pressure]" but given "degree_Celsius", `dewpoint` requires "[temperature]" but given "millibar"
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace it looks like you are not using the code that you posted into the question.

Your function call is: `mpcalc.precipitable_water(dew, pressure)` but it should be `mpcalc.precipitable_water(pressure, dew)`

As noted in the stacktrace, the function call changed in 1.0. So pay attention to the order of the arguments in your function.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. The code in my question is pasted straight from my script. I can't understand why it seems to be saying the order of arguments is reversed.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the arguments? Also the code that you pasted in the question would never run, because you never import `precipitable_water` so this can't be the code you are actually using.

Comment: I'm on a work computer without Python at the moment, but I'm wondering if it's a matter of just changing the last line to this:  pw = mpcalc.precipitable_water(pressure,dewpoint)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I had wrong. Here's a working script in case it helps anyone else:

```
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
    from metpy.units import units
    import numpy as np

    pressure = np.array([1000, 500]) * units.mbar
    dewpoint = np.array([11.5, -25]) * units.degC
    pw = mpcalc.precipitable_water(pressure,dewpoint)

    print(pw)
```